# Conversion from MikroBasic to MikroC

Tags: mikroc

Can anyone help me with this conversion from MikroBasic to MikroC?

in MB:
    FormattedDataString = text + "," + text1 + "," + text2 
my effort in C :
    FormattedDataString = (text + "," + text1 + "," + text2);
    char FormattedDataString [100];
    char text,text1,text2;

Regards
Sarel

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the function `strcat`. The prototype definition is:

`char *strcat(char *to, char *from);`

The first line will be to copy text to FormattedDataString using `strcpy`. The prototype definition is:

```
char *strcpy(char *to, char *from);
```

So it's like:

```
strcpy(FormattedDataString, text);
strcat(FormattedDataString, ",");
strcat(FormattedDataString, text1);
strcat(FormattedDataString, ",");
strcat(FormattedDataString, text2);
```

Please refer to the help section of MikroC.